# libgdx particle system on Android Canvas

Tags: android, drawing, libgdx, particle-system

Is it possible to use the libGDX Particle Effect library for drawing on an Android `Canvas`?
I don't want to rewrite all my application to use libGDX `ApplicationListener`. I would like to use the libGDX [Particle Editor](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ParticleEditor) to add particle effects to my app, but all drawing in my app is in a canvas `onDraw` method. Help please!

Answer (score 0):

No, not easily.  The libGDX Particle Editor emits a file format that is suitable for loading into the libGDX [ParticleEffect](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/ParticleEffect.html) class.  It uses many libGDX drawing primitives to actually draw the effect.  Most drawing in libGDX is actually a thin wrapper around OpenGL, and is generally easy to map to OpenGL.  I don't think Canvas (Android Canvas I'm assuming?) would be easy.

That said, libGDX is all open source, so you could read and parse the particle files.  And you can see how the [ParticleEffect](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/ParticleEffect.java) and [ParticleEmitter](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/ParticleEmitter.java) actually implement particle effects.